# .net mvc3 DropDownList with angularjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like do a DropDownList with `@Html.DropDownList` and bind with AngularJS.

The code

```
@Html.DropDownList("LessionID", (SelectList)ViewBag.LessionList, "chose one", new { ng_model = "LessionID" })
```

suggesst the data like
[LessionID:1,LessionName:English][LessionID:2,LessionName:Sport]......

then html code

```
<select id="LessionID" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="LessionID" name="LessionID">
   <option value="? object:null ?"></option>
   <option value="">chose one</option>
   <option value="1">English</option>
   <option value="2">Sport</option>
```

How does the first option show?

Can it remove?

Answer (score 0):

First option can be removed by setting your scope variable to a default in your controller. You have chosen the name LessionID for the name of your scope variable to which your dropdown list is bound to. I presume you have missed out setting this $scope.LessionID to a default, so it is undefined and rendering a spurious dropdown entry value [?/null]

code:

```js
function LessionCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.LessionID = '';

  $scope.alertLession = function() {
    alert($scope.LessionID);
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Lession</h2>
  <div ng-controller="LessionCtrl">
    <select id="LessionID" ng-model="LessionID" ng-change="alertLession()" name="LessionID">
      <option value="">chose one</option>
      <option value="1">English</option>
      <option value="2">Sport</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```